# Making a map with a legend in map composer with PyQGIS 3.0

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I am trying to make a map in map composer with PyQgis (API-3)
Anyway, I have the color-ramped multipolygon and I want to display it with a legend and to save it as .jpg. Here is my code, with no error, but on the output I get nothing.

```
#path to qgis
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr/lib/qgis", True)
app = QgsApplication([], True)
app.initQgis()


saveAsSHP = 'MYFILE.shp'
layerInput = QgsVectorLayer(saveAsSHP,"Legend", "ogr")

#color ramp
population = (
    ("0 - 10055", 0.0, 10055.0, "cyan"),
    ("10055 - 20055", 10055.0, 20055.0, "blue"),
    ("20055 - 30055", 20055.0, 30055.0, "green"),
    ("30055 - 50055", 30055.0, 50055.0, "yellow"),
    ("50055 - 60055", 50055.0, 60055.0, "orange"),
    ("60055 - 70055", 60055.0, 70055.0, "red"),
    ("70055 - 80055", 70055.0, 80055.0, "pink"),
    ("80055 - 90055", 80055.0, 90055.0, "silver"),
    ("90055 - 12055", 90055.0, 12055.0, "purple"),
    ("12055 - 280055", 12055.0, 280055.0, "white")
    )
ranges = []

for label, lower, upper, color in population:
    sym = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(layerInput.geometryType())
    sym.setColor(QColor(color))
    rng = QgsRendererRange(lower,upper,sym,label)
    ranges.append(rng)
field = 'Total-Traf'
renderer = QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer(field,ranges)
layerInput.setRenderer(renderer)

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layerInput)


#CREATING A MAP

reg = QgsProject.instance()
reg.addMapLayer(layerInput)
mr = iface.mapCanvas().mapRenderer()
qc = QgsLayout.MapComposer(qmlr=reg, qmr=mr)

#legend
qc.legend = QgsLayoutItemLegend(qc.c)
qc.legend.model().setLayers(qc.mr.layerSet)
qc.legend.setItemPosition(5, qc.y)
qc.c.addItem(qc.legend)
qc.output("PATH/map.jpg", "jpg")


#closing qgis
app.exec_()
app.exitQgis()
```